# Is extending stock knockout objects a good practice in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, best-practice

I'm writing an extra step in the M2 checkout. There are already written well structured models and actions in `Magento_Checkout/js`. Should I extend them (for instance `js/model/quote` or `js/model/resource-url-manager`) with underscore's `_.extend()` , or rather create my own from scratch?